# two dimensional change of variable

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int{\frac{\sin^2(q.(x_1-x_2))}{q^2}d^2q}
\end{equation}
The notation $d^n q_k$ to indicate integral over the $n$ coordinates of a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How to perform the integration of the integral above?

Comment: So $\mathrm d^2q$ would mean $\mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2$? Also, what's the domain of integration? All of $\mathrm R^2$?

Comment: all of $R^2$ , $\mathrm d^2q$ would mean $dq_1 dq_2$ and $q\neq q(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates? You have skipped the dot product in the argument of the sine squared. In polar coordinates, said argument is $q \cos \theta ~ |\vec x_1-\vec x_2|$.

Comment: yeah i missed that,can elaborate your idea of doing the integration in the polar coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In polar coordinates, $q^2\equiv \vec q \cdot \vec q$,
$$
\int d^2 q= \int_0^\infty \!\! q ~dq ~\int _0^{2\pi} d\theta 
$$
and use $(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)$ to fix the arbitrary origin of $\theta$, so $\vec q \cdot (\vec x_1-\vec x_2)=q |(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)| \cos \theta$, hence, as virtually always,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int{\frac{\sin^2(\vec q\cdot (\vec x_1-\vec x_2))}{q^2}d^2q} \\ = 
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int _0^{2\pi} d\theta ~\int_0^\infty \!\! \frac{dq}{q} ~  \sin^2( q ~|(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)| ~\cos\theta )  . 
\end{equation}

Now the scale $  |(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)| \cos\theta$ may be absorbed into the definition of *q* and the integral in $\theta$ be performed, so the above reduces to
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi } \int_0^\infty \!\! \frac{dq}{q} ~  \sin^2 q   = \infty .
$$